Can I make a Heading block above a query loop block disappear when that query loop has no results?
I have a query loop that disappears (by design) when it has no results (by not including a "No Results" block). I would like to find a way of making the Heading that precedes the query loop also disappear at the same time.
The reason is that this pattern (Heading/Query loop) is repeated on 100 different posts, only some of which have any results. I want the Heading block to appear ONLY when the query loop has results.

If by "disappear" you mean "not visible", this could be solved with css. If you want to prevent the heading from being generated at all, you would have to do some post processing on the page, as the header's html will already have been generated by the time you reach the query block

I mean not visible. Can we make CSS for heading block depend on query loop results in the following block?

Depending on how complex the html is (this depends on your theme) you can do this with css combinators alone or you would use a piece of jquery to check emptiness on one block and then add a class to the heading block, to trigger a css rule.

Thanks. I think that is all too complicated for my skills and what I want to achieve. I shall try a different t approach. THanks anyway.
